# setting the width on a fieldset in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, width, fieldset

Hello I am a beginner in codeigniter framework and I have a problem with fieldsets in codeigniter.
I would like to make a fieldset that have a certain width, for example i would do this in html :

```
    <fieldset style="width: 350px">
        <legend>Login Form</legend>  
    <?php 
    echo form_open("user/login"); 
    ?>
        <table>
    <tr> <td> <label for="user">Username:</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="email" name="username"  /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> <label for="pass">Password:</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="pass" name="password"  /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> <input type="reset" class="" value="Clear form" /> </td> <td> <input type="submit" class="" value="Sign in" /> </td> </tr>
        </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </fieldset>
```

and i dont know how to achieve that using active record :

```
    <?php 
    echo form_fieldset('Login Form');
    echo form_open("user/login"); 
    ?>
        <table>
    <tr> <td> <label for="user">Username:</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="email" name="username"  /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> <label for="pass">Password:</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="pass" name="password"  /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> <input type="reset" class="" value="Clear form" /> </td> <td> <input type="submit" class="" value="Sign in" /> </td> </tr>
        </table>
    <?php 
    echo form_close(); 
    echo form_fieldset_close();
    ?>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$attributes = array('style' => 'width: 350px');
echo form_fieldset('Login Form', $attributes);
```